# .NET 6 Serilog, how to append logs to the same daily file and not creating a new one when app has stopped and re-run

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, serilog

I have a dotnet app, and it currently stores only 31 log files in log folder, and that should be fine because I want to store only files for a month at max. The problem that I am having is that the server is behind some service that stops the app when it does not have any request and then it runs it again if a user sends a request and that has caused (I think) to change the naming convention of log files in my logs directory.

So according to the configs, the name of a log file should be `log-{year}{month}{day}.txt` but when it stops and then the app again, then it becomes like this: `log-{year}{month}{day}_001.txt` and next re-run `log-{year}{month}{day}_002.txt` etc.

Below I am posting my `UseSerilog` config from `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
            configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Serilog", LogEventLevel.Error)
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
          .Enrich.WithClientIp()
          .Enrich.WithClientAgent()
          .WriteTo.Console()
    );
```

This is the config from `appsettings.json`

```json
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo"
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "WithClientIp",
      "WithClientAgent"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {ClientIp}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {ClientIp} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

and this is my `web.config` I added this file to the root directory to enable the server to write, I copied from the web and I am not sure what each line does exactly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Demo.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <handlerSettings>
          <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value=".\logs\debug.log" />
          <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="FILE,TRACE" />
        </handlerSettings>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Is there any config that I can change so that the logger will be appending logs to the same daily file, and not creating a new one when the app has stopped and run after again? I was reading the serilog docs, and one way was to increase `retainedFileCountLimit` from 31 that is default to some larger number, but that is not exactly a solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi @Sachhiro, I was not able to replicate the behavior you are describing. Using your code Serilog is behaving like you expected it to do. Obviously I do no have access to `Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo` but I do not think that the culprit can be found in there.

Can you probably share your `csproj` file so we can have a look at the versions you are using?

Comment: @exeC13 it woks fine in dev env to me too, but not in prod or staging. I am using latest packages of Serilog